# Localhost already in use (Pycharm and mongodb)

Tags: python3, webapps, localhost, mongodb, pycharm

I've been creating a webapp from a course in PyCharm and using mongodb for the database. 
I was finishing it and executed "Run" in pycharm before running the server.

Realizing my mistake I closed it, but when I ran mongod in the terminal and tried to test the app through pycharm this error appeared in the console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/PyCharmProjects/web_blog/src/app.py", line 106, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/home/user/Documents/pyenv/webblog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/user/Documents/pyenv/webblog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 739, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/user/Documents/pyenv/webblog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 699, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/home/user/Documents/pyenv/webblog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 593, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/home/user/Documents/pyenv/webblog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 504, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I've tried purging and reinstalling mongodb and nothing changes (I supposed it wouldn't since mongod is running normally, before uninstalling and after reinstalling). 
Is there a way to "clean" my localhost or at least change the port where the mongodb database is running (it's currently on: 127.0.0.1:27017)?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Purging and reinstalling typically is unhelpful in Linux. You would configure monogodb in the config file and restart - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#file-format . The error message you are getting is because monogodb is already running. Stop the server or do not start if from your script.

Answer (score 0):

We can kill or stop the **Network Port** used by the **Webapp**. This will help you to resolve the issue.

```
sudo lsof -i :8000
```

or

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
sudo fuser -n tcp -k 8000
```